# ActionBarDrawerToggle изменение иконки

Tags: android, android-sdk

Как изменить стандартную иконку изображающую три полоски на другую, например ведро или стрелку, направленную в правую сторону?

Comment: Это пробовали? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32507318/3212712

Comment: Вот ещё: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32695966/3212712

Comment: И ещё: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29960782/3212712

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960782/3212712)

```
//убираем иконку
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
//устанавливаем свою в тулбар
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.menu_icon);
//назначаем слушатель нажатий
mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          //для примера откроем дровер по нажатию
          mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
     }
});
```

Comment: Это я уже делал и оно не работает  с "syncState()  " (( а почему не знаю.   mtoggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        mtoggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_format_list_bulleted);

        drawer.setDrawerListener(mtoggle);
        mtoggle.syncState();//если это убрать то работает

Comment: @semiromid, в данном случае и не должно работать - ведь нечего синкать - индикатора (иконки) нема, т.к. он отключён.

Comment: Так а что делает этот индикатор? Или что делает syncState() для индикатора?

Comment: @semiromid, насколько я понимаю/знаю, индикатор делает НЯшную анимацию при открытии/закрытии дровера. А синкСтейт должен обновлять картинку его (палочки/стрелочка) в некоторых особых случаях. В любом случае вызов этого метода лучше оставить как в примерах/доках если вы пользуете стандартную иконку. Если свою - то, думаю, он не будет нужен.